# is assignment of variables legal inside an Interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface

```
public interface GroupedInterface extends Interface1, Interface2, Interface3 {

    // constant declarations

    // base of natural logarithms
    double E = 2.718282;

    // method signatures
    void doSomething (int i, double x);
    int doSomethingElse(String s);
}
```

(I'm studying from oracle's site.This is from there.)It's an interface definition and but we assign a number to E of type double. Is it possible all variables can declare x,y,z of type int and then assign some number to them (is it constant declaration or constant declaration is what? )?? Does E have special condition or etc. in the above code??

Comment: @EricR. An interface can extend multiple interfaces. The code compiles fine.

Comment: @fgb my bad :( I was thinking in term of class.  I remove my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable declared in an interface are `static` and `final` by default, and are allowed. So you can set an initial value for the variables but not change them.

Comment: about Interfaces, can i also do some verification there? like an 'if'?